# Python 2 Different Date Time in Second

Tags: python, datetime

```
from datetime import datetime, date, time
import time

fmt = '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'
d1 = datetime.now
time.sleep(5)
d2 = datetime.now
diff = (d2-d1).seconds
print(diff)
```

i get the error message with

```
diff = (d2-d1).seconds
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'builtin_function_or_method' and 'builtin_function_or_method'
```

how to different the two datetime in seconds format?

Comment: Dude! You cannot change the entire question!

Comment: Please revert to the original question and open another topic for the question you posted last. The answers are no in no correlation to your question.

Comment: simply start another topic. There's no harm in opening as many topics as you like (as long as they contain relevant questions).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing your brackets `()` after `now`:

```
from datetime import datetime, date, time
import time

fmt = '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'
d1 = datetime.now()
time.sleep(5)
d2 = datetime.now()
diff = (d2-d1).seconds
print(diff)
```

Answer (score 0):

`now` is a function, so what you are trying to subtract are two functions. Try this:
`datetime.now() - datetime.now()`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are not calling the datetime.now function, you are merely assigning d1 and d2 to the reference of the function. This should solve your problem:

```
d1 = datetime.now() # note the function call
d2 = datetime.now()
```